# I would like to search by filtering by date in mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to have the total of names that do not have "SENT" as status and I would also like to filter this number according to a date of beginning and end, for the moment only the first part walks it marks the filtering by the dated. my field is called "date".
sorry my code did not indent ):

```
db.name.aggregate([{ $group: {_id:"$id", sent: 
{$max: {$cond: {if: { 
$eq: [ "$status", "SENT" ] }, then: 1, else: 0}}} } },
{ $match: { sent: 
0 } }, {$count: "total"}])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your query to add the `$match` as first stage and include date and status filter followed by `$count` stage to count the matched documents.

Something like

```
db.name.aggregate([
    {"$match": {"status":"SENT","date":{"$gte":input date1, "$lte":input date2} }
    {"$count": "total"} 
])
```

You don't need aggregation for the request. You can use regular queries.

```
db.name.count({"status":"SENT","date":{"$gte":input date1, "$lte":input date2} })
```